# DataTables - Next/Previous pagination links to show next/previous full group of page numbers

Tags: javascript, datatables

In DataTables, is there any configuration or tweaks so that when I click on next, the complete next pages would appear?

For example, in current implementation, on clicking next button, the page shifts to only one, i.e.

**first 1 2 3 4 ... next** is shifted to **first ...,2,3,4,5,... next**

But I need the implementation:

**first 1,2,3,4,... next**. When clicked to next: **first ...,5,6,7,8,... next**.

How can I make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you write a plugin.

I have modified the now deprecate [Ellipses plugin](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/ellipses) to include an option for grouping the pagination numbers. This was tested with DataTables 1.10.7 and 1.9.4.

In your JavaScript, when you instantiate DataTables, use the `pagingNumbersGrouping` option to get the behavior you're after. I have made it default to `false`, so anyone can replace the original plugin with this one without breaking any current implementation.

```js
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "pagingType": "ellipses",         // use "sPaginationType" for DataTables v1.9 and earlier
    "showPages": 4,                   // default is 5
    "pagingNumbersGrouping": true,    // default is false
    "pagingExtraNumberForNext": true  // default is false, affects pagingNumbersGrouping behavior:
                                      //   when false: previous 1 2 3 4 ... next, (click next)
                                      //               previous ... 5 6 7 8 ... next
                                      //   when true: previous 1 2 3 4 5 ... next, (click "5" or next)
                                      //              previous ... 5 6 7 8 9 ... next
});
```

**ellipses.js**

```js
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    'sPageEllipsis': 'paginate_ellipsis',
    'sPageNumber': 'paginate_number',
    'sPageNumbers': 'paginate_numbers',
    'sPageFirst': "first",           // These are 
    'sPagePrevious': "previous",     // necessary for
    'sPageNext': "next",             // newer versions
    'sPageLast': "last"              // of DataTables (>= 1.10)
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.ellipses = {
    'oDefaults': {
        'showPages': 5,
        'pagingNumbersGrouping': false,
        'pagingExtraNumberForNext': false
    },
    'fnClickHandler': function (e) {
        var fnCallbackDraw = e.data.fnCallbackDraw,
            oSettings = e.data.oSettings,
            sPage = e.data.sPage;

        if ($(this).is('[disabled]')) {
            return false;
        }

        oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, sPage);
        fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);

        return true;
    },
    // fnInit is called once for each instance of pager
    'fnInit': function (oSettings, nPager, fnCallbackDraw) {
        var oClasses = oSettings.oClasses,
            oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate,
            that = this;

        var showPages = oSettings.oInit.showPages || this.oDefaults.showPages,
            showPagesHalf = Math.floor(showPages / 2),
            pagingNumbersGrouping = oSettings.oInit.pagingNumbersGrouping || this.oDefaults.pagingNumbersGrouping,
            pagingExtraNumberForNext = oSettings.oInit.pagingExtraNumberForNext || this.oDefaults.pagingExtraNumberForNext;

        $.extend(oSettings, {
            _showPages: showPages,
            _showPagesHalf: showPagesHalf,
            _pagingNumbersGrouping: pagingNumbersGrouping,
            _pagingExtraNumberForNext: pagingExtraNumberForNext
        });

        var oFirst = $('<a class="' + oClasses.sPageButton + ' ' + oClasses.sPageFirst + '">' + oLang.sFirst + '</a>'),
            oPrevious = $('<a class="' + oClasses.sPageButton + ' ' + oClasses.sPagePrevious + '">' + oLang.sPrevious + '</a>'),
            oNumbers = $('<span class="' + oClasses.sPageNumbers + '"></span>'),
            oNext = $('<a class="' + oClasses.sPageButton + ' ' + oClasses.sPageNext + '">' + oLang.sNext + '</a>'),
            oLast = $('<a class="' + oClasses.sPageButton + ' ' + oClasses.sPageLast + '">' + oLang.sLast + '</a>');

        oFirst.click({ 'fnCallbackDraw': fnCallbackDraw, 'oSettings': oSettings, 'sPage': 'first' }, that.fnClickHandler);
        oPrevious.click({ 'fnCallbackDraw': fnCallbackDraw, 'oSettings': oSettings, 'sPage': 'previous' }, that.fnClickHandler);
        oNext.click({ 'fnCallbackDraw': fnCallbackDraw, 'oSettings': oSettings, 'sPage': 'next' }, that.fnClickHandler);
        oLast.click({ 'fnCallbackDraw': fnCallbackDraw, 'oSettings': oSettings, 'sPage': 'last' }, that.fnClickHandler);

        // Draw
        $(nPager).append(oFirst, oPrevious, oNumbers, oNext, oLast);
    },
    // fnUpdate is only called once while table is rendered
    'fnUpdate': function (oSettings, fnCallbackDraw) {
        var oClasses = oSettings.oClasses,
            that = this;

        var tableWrapper = oSettings.nTableWrapper;

        // Update stateful properties
        this.fnUpdateState(oSettings);

        if (oSettings._iCurrentPage === 1) {
            $('.' + oClasses.sPageFirst, tableWrapper).attr('disabled', true);
            $('.' + oClasses.sPagePrevious, tableWrapper).attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.' + oClasses.sPageFirst, tableWrapper).removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.' + oClasses.sPagePrevious, tableWrapper).removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        if (oSettings._iTotalPages === 0 || oSettings._iCurrentPage === oSettings._iTotalPages) {
            $('.' + oClasses.sPageNext, tableWrapper).attr('disabled', true);
            $('.' + oClasses.sPageLast, tableWrapper).attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.' + oClasses.sPageNext, tableWrapper).removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.' + oClasses.sPageLast, tableWrapper).removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        var i, oNumber, oNumbers = $('.' + oClasses.sPageNumbers, tableWrapper);

        // Erase
        oNumbers.html('');

        for (i = oSettings._iFirstPage; i <= oSettings._iLastPage; i++) {
            oNumber = $('<a class="' + oClasses.sPageButton + ' ' + oClasses.sPageNumber + '">' + oSettings.fnFormatNumber(i) + '</a>');

            if (oSettings._iCurrentPage === i) {
                oNumber.attr('active', true).attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                oNumber.click({ 'fnCallbackDraw': fnCallbackDraw, 'oSettings': oSettings, 'sPage': i - 1 }, that.fnClickHandler);
            }

            // Draw
            oNumbers.append(oNumber);
        }

        // Add ellipses
        if (1 < oSettings._iFirstPage) {
            oNumbers.prepend('<span class="' + oClasses.sPageEllipsis + '">...</span>');
        }

        if (oSettings._iLastPage < oSettings._iTotalPages) {
            oNumbers.append('<span class="' + oClasses.sPageEllipsis + '">...</span>');
        }
    },
    // fnUpdateState used to be part of fnUpdate
    // The reason for moving is so we can access current state info before fnUpdate is called
    'fnUpdateState': function (oSettings) {
        var iCurrentPage = Math.ceil((oSettings._iDisplayStart + 1) / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
            iTotalPages = Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
            iFirstPage,
            iLastPage;

        // Added, calculating pagingNumbersGrouping
        if (oSettings._pagingNumbersGrouping) {
            var pageSet = Math.ceil(iCurrentPage / oSettings._showPages);
            iLastPage = pageSet * oSettings._showPages;
            iFirstPage = iLastPage - (oSettings._showPages - 1);
            if (oSettings._pagingExtraNumberForNext) {
                iLastPage++;
            }
        } else {
            iFirstPage = iCurrentPage - oSettings._showPagesHalf;
            iLastPage = iCurrentPage + oSettings._showPagesHalf;
        }

        if (iTotalPages < oSettings._showPages) {
            iFirstPage = 1;
            iLastPage = iTotalPages;
        } else if (iFirstPage < 1) {
            iFirstPage = 1;
            iLastPage = oSettings._showPages;
        } else if (iLastPage > iTotalPages) {
            if (!oSettings._pagingNumbersGrouping) {
                iFirstPage = (iTotalPages - oSettings._showPages) + 1;
            }
            iLastPage = iTotalPages;
        }

        $.extend(oSettings, {
            _iCurrentPage: iCurrentPage,
            _iTotalPages: iTotalPages,
            _iFirstPage: iFirstPage,
            _iLastPage: iLastPage
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: The code is working like a charm. Can we fine tune the pages in such a way that if I select the last page then the pages automatically starts from the given page followed by new pages?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include an option for that, `pagingExtraNumberForNext`, just set it to `true`.